# Airflow - no module named "airflow.providers" or "airflow.contrib.providers"

Tags: python, docker, airflow

We are trying to import both `MongoHook` and `GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator` into our Airflow Project:

- [docs for MongoHook](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/airflow/providers/mongo/hooks/mongo/index.html#module-airflow.providers.mongo.hooks.mongo)
- [docs for GCS Operator](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/operator/google/transfer/gcs_to_local.html)

...per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61275596/airflow-unable-to-access-the-aws-providers), *"Providers package is no longer included with Airflow, but you can separately install them with pip using the specific backport package"*

I have had no luck with this. For our DockerFile, we started using [this image](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/Dockerfile) from the puckel/docker-airflow repo on GitHub.

I've tried adding these two lines to our `requirements.txt`

```
apache-airflow-backport-providers-mongo
apache-airflow-backport-providers-google
```

...and I've tried adding these lines to our DockerFile:

```
    && pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-mongo \
    && pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-google \
```

...and we're getting the errors mentioned in the title. How can I install these into our docker image/container to use them in our Airflow project?

**edit:** checking quickly to see if the issue was that I simply wasn't rebuilding the image

**edit2:** rebuilding the image was needed; however, now we are receiving the error `No module named 'airflow.utils.process_utils'`, which we get when importing `GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator`. Not sure why Airflow took `providers` out of the base install, this is very frustrating...

Answer (score 2):

The answer to my original question was that I needed to rebuild the docker image (DOH).

The answer to my second question, I think, was that I was installing these packages twice (once with an explicit pip install in the Dockerfile, and once in the requirements.txt, which is also pip installed in the Dockerfile). When I removed the duplicate install, it seems to be working now.

Comment: Which one did you removed? the one from the Dockerfile or the one from requirements.txt? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am also curious about this question, as I'm running into the same error. I tried running `pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-google` in my docker environment, after running `docker exec -it airflow bash` and my airflow container refuses to run now